# Why does the heartless vanitas in kingdom hearts almost exactly resemble sora?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

Why does vanitas look almost exactly like sora?

Comment: @F1Krazy can you answer? It´s just puzzled me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to the events of Birth By Sleep, there was a point in time where Sora's and [Ventus](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Ventus)' hearts connected

> After a brief discussion, Ventus's heart connects with Sora's, mending his broken heart and allowing Ven to stay alive until he someday becomes strong enough to repair the damage by himself

This connection, as Tetsuya Nomura states, is the reason why [Vanitas](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Vanitas) resembles Sora. This resemblance wouldn't only reflect on Sora - if anybody had connected to Ventus' heart like Sora had, Vanitas would have resembled them as well

> In an interview with Tetsuya Nomura as well as various novelizations of the game, it is revealed that this similarity is due to Sora's heart connecting with Ventus near the beginning of the game, and had anyone else connected with Ventus's heart, Vanitas would look like that person

Comment: The strange thing is that the heart of ventus was damaged by extracting the darkness which formed vanitas. The heartlinking happened after that.(If i remember correctly)

Comment: @MartinH.You are correct on that, but they OP asked why Vanitus resembled Sora and not what created Vanitus :) I intentionally left that part out to avoid potential spoilers

Comment: wondercricket´s got a point.